# ReactJs axios post request getting though another component and used .map insde

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Someone has nicely answered the POST request here:  [Create an axios post with multiple inputs using React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277874/create-an-axios-post-with-multiple-inputs-using-react-hooks)
I tested and worked. My issue is little complicated, instead of using direct html as given  from example:

````
<input type="text" name="lastName" value={formData.language} onChange={handleChange} required/>```
I have a component named "Form" which return following
````

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor={props.id}>Choose {props.name}:</label>
            <select name={props.id} id={props.id}>
                <option name={props.id} id={props.id} >Any</option>
                {props.fieldDesc.map((desc, index) =>
                    <option key={index} name={props.id} value={desc} onChange={handleChange} id={props.id}>{desc}</option>
                )}
            </select>
```

```
with the above I am able to use this <options> thing with no of options I get from a route. Problem comes when I use the above "Form" component 4 times in another component like this:
```

Submit

```
with this way after submitting I get this in console while onChnage also doesnt bring something in console:
{language: "", degreeType: "", deptName: "", presenceType: ""}

but not the values of the props, I need props and then make POST request which will help me for filter the data on the homepage with the selection options above.  
Its my first week with ReactJS and rather technical situation for me. I hope I made the uestion clear. here is how my frontend look like.
[enter image description here][1]

Looking forward to the answer. Thanks 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2pAC.png
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value={desc}` should be replaced by `value={formData.someInputVariable}` so that once the form is submitted it can read the values from here correctly.